# Basic Cursor Movement Between Paragraphs in Matlab Editor

Tags: matlab, editor

Is there a way to move between paragraphs in the Matlab Editor as is a common feature in any other general text editor out there. ie. 
Ctrl+Up and Ctrl+Down to Move cursor between paragraphs as in Winedt.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is such a shortcut. I must admit I have never missed it myself - what would a "paragraph" in your code be defined as?

BTW, are you aware that `Ctrl+Down` is used to go from one Cell to the next in MATLAB's [cell mode](http://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/news_notes/dec04/cellmode.html)? Cells could be considered logical "paragraphs" of your code, and you set their limits themselves (with comment lines starting with a double `%%`).

Comment: Yes I am aware of this, and I am using it. But all other editors that I have worked with ie. Utraedit, etc have this facility. To clarify what I am after,